# Exact Definition of electrostatic field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, definition

1. Some documents define an electrostatic field as the electric field of a stationary charge or steady current.
2. However, in other documents, they are defined them as electric fields satisfying $\nabla \times \vec{E}=0 $.
3. And another defines them as electric field that do not change with time.

I know that the case in 1,3 implies that case 2 (maybe 3 implis 2).

But, I think any case that corresponds to 3 may not correspond to 1 or 2.

Thus, I think the above 3 definitions are not exactly the same.

is there anything I think wrong? Or, please give me the exact definition.

Comment: 3 and 2  implies 1. 1 does not imply 2 and 3, (unless we have suitable boundary conditions like the fields go to zero at infinity)

Comment: Does it matter as long as it's clear from context which of the three definitions is used? What's the *physics* question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Static* means something that does not change in time, that is
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}=0.$$

The [Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Formulation_in_SI_units_convention) defining electric field are:
$$
\nabla \cdot  \mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}\\
\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
$$
The second equation means that we may get a static electric field due to a time-varying magnetic field (that is a magnetic field growing linearly in time.) Magnetic field is created due to electric currents and/or time-varying electric field, as another Maxwell equation states:
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_0\left(\mathbf{J}+\varepsilon_0\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\right)
$$
that is, in principle, we could have a non-zero curl of the electric field constant in time due to a time-dependent current. However, this would mean time-dependent electric field via the equation for the divergence.

In other words, static electric field implies zero curl, but not necessarily zero current - the current simply has to be constant in time, resulting in a constant magnetic field. (In some cases charges can made static by switching to a reference frame moving along the current, but this is not possible in case of more complex current distribution - e.g., several crossing wires.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, those conditions are not the same.

$\nabla \times \vec{E} = 0$ does not necessarily imply that the field is electrostatic. The well-known example is induced electric field of ideal infinite solenoid on its outside. If solenoid surface current changes linearly in time, induced electric field outside is constant and circulating around the solenoid, but this is not an electrostatic field.

Electrostatic field is electric field that occurs due to static distribution of electric charge only, where current and rate of change of current vanishes (these have to vanish for some enough time in the past, due to finite speed of propagation of field changes).

Comment: Would a linearly increasing current distribution not have  a static charge density? $$\vec{J} = t\delta(r-r_{0}) \hat \theta$$  $$\nabla \cdot \vec{J} = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} ( t \delta(r-r_{0})) = 0 $$ $$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = 0$$

Comment: When you have non-zero current or rate of change of current (acceleration), charges are moving and produce different field, thus such charges are not static. Net charge density may be constant in time, but it is not an electrostatic situation. I've added this detail to my answer.

Comment: The situation you described is also not a valid counter example for the condition posed.  db/dt is not zero for your situation

Comment: Which condition posed?

Comment: Arent you saying Curl of E = 0 doesn't imply electrostatics, and then are providing  counter example using this Supposed condition?

Comment: I don't suppose db/dt is zero everywhere. Outside the solenoid it is, inside it is not.